# End user documentation for Django Admin

Tags: django

Does anyone know of any end user documentation for the Django admin site?  Just explaining in end user terms about creating user accounts, how model permissions work, that sort of stuff?

I know someone's going to refer me to the documentation, but whilst it's excellent for us techies it's not aimed at non techies.

Thanks!

Ludo.

Answer (score 2):

I use sphinx to generate end user documentation. Also, I made library with few features to make producing documentation easier, like auto documenting models and creating skeleton for documentation. django-simpleadmindoc is available on github:

https://github.com/bmihelac/django-simpleadmindoc

Of course, you would still have to write the documentation yourself.

Comment: I think by "End User Documentation" the OP actually means the non technical people who end up using it. Correct me if I am wrong but that is not what your app does at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the *user* of a website utilzing Django's built-in administration interface and not the person(s) who developed the site, then you may want to contact them. The Django admin is a great convenience for us developers, however, we as developers ultimately have to provide the non-techy end users with documentation on how to use the website we've built for them.

Comment: Hi.  I'm a developer rather than a user, and yeah, I hear what you're saying that it's up to us to provide the documentation, I just thought it must be a common requirement so wondered if someone might have done so already.  Cheers.